# Does the exclamation mark denote anger when used with a command?

Tags: imperativo

I want to make it clear that I intend `"Pasa la aspiradora en el dormitorio"`" to mean `"You, vacuum the bedroom"` instead of `"He vacuums the bedroom"`. Adding `¡!` around the sentence would certainly turn it into a command, but I am afraid that the exclamations denote anger. In English, exclamation marks around a command usually denote anger or anxiety. I wonder if it is the same in Spanish. I want it to be a casual instruction, not an anxious command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on context, really. Exclamations do not necessarily denote anger, but it might indeed imply too much emphasis for a casual instruction. Some alternatives that remove the ambiguity:

> Juan, pasa la aspiradora en el dormitorio.
>
> Por favor, pasa la aspiradora en el dormitorio.
>
> ¿Puedes pasar la aspiradora en el dormitorio?
>
> Te encargo que pases la aspiradora en el dormitorio.

Comment: I will not be speaking directly to the person. Rather I will be writing it on a piece of paper. So I don't know how much the context can help.

Comment: Then you could safely use the last 3 expressions already mentioned because they can be considered as friendly/casual instructions.

Comment: I actuallly find the 1st one more usual for a written note left on a table. It is very likely to see a signature after that, like "Juan, pasa la aspiradora luego. Mamá". Anyways, adding a "por favor" in all of them is free and it is always better.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `"Pasa la aspiradora en el dormitorio"` without the exclamation marks because it is an instruction, not an order. Usually, orders go with exclamation marks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `"Pasa la aspiradora en el dormitorio, por favor"` to make it clear that you are asking for something to be done.

I would prefer to make it conditional: `"¿Podrías pasar la aspiradora en el dormitorio?"`. It is a quite polite way to ask for something and it is normally clear that it is a conditional, but you want it done.

If you used `"¡Pasa la aspiradora en el dormitorio!"` it could sound too imperative.

What is not to be said is `"Tú, pasa la aspiradora en el dormitorio"`, because it shows too much anxiety and a relation of power in which you can  give orders to other people.